# We could have been getting married but

Tags: modal-verbs

1. We **could be getting** married this (next) Saturday but the wedding needed to be postponed for obvious reasons.
2. We **could have been getting** married this (next) Saturday but the wedding needed to be postponed for obvious reasons.

Which is correct?

Comment: "We could be getting married" means that the wedding is still possible.

Comment: Does sentence (2) sound correct?

Comment: As the answer says, **should have been** would be more appropriate for a planned date that had to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**could** suggests that something might have been possible. You probably should use **should**, which suggests that something was planned to happen.

**should be** suggests that something will probably go ahead, whereas **should have been** suggests that it was planned to go ahead but it isn't going to happen as planned.

The "obvious reasons" make it clear that you didn't choose to cancel it- you had to do so. It would therefore be OK to replace **needed to be** with **was**, without changing the meaning.

The correct sentence is therefore

> We should have been getting married this (next) Saturday but the wedding was postponed for obvious reasons.